# Bomblab - phase 5 - Arrays in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

So I'm working on the infamous bomblab project for school and I'm stuck on phase 5. For those of you not familiar with bomblab it's a project which entails reading assembly code to determine the correct input required to defuse various binary "bombs". The following is the assembly code for phase 5.

```
Dump of assembler code for function phase_5:
=> 0x0000000000401077 <+0>:     sub    $0x18,%rsp
0x000000000040107b <+4>:     lea    0x8(%rsp),%rcx
0x0000000000401080 <+9>:     lea    0xc(%rsp),%rdx
0x0000000000401085 <+14>:    mov    $0x4028c5,%esi
0x000000000040108a <+19>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
0x000000000040108f <+24>:    callq  0x400c30 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
0x0000000000401094 <+29>:    cmp    $0x1,%eax
0x0000000000401097 <+32>:    jg     0x40109e <phase_5+39>
0x0000000000401099 <+34>:    callq  0x401574 <explode_bomb>
0x000000000040109e <+39>:    mov    0xc(%rsp),%eax
0x00000000004010a2 <+43>:    and    $0xf,%eax
0x00000000004010a5 <+46>:    mov    %eax,0xc(%rsp)
0x00000000004010a9 <+50>:    cmp    $0xf,%eax
0x00000000004010ac <+53>:    je     0x4010da <phase_5+99>
0x00000000004010ae <+55>:    mov    $0x0,%ecx
0x00000000004010b3 <+60>:    mov    $0x0,%edx
0x00000000004010b8 <+65>:    add    $0x1,%edx
0x00000000004010bb <+68>:    cltq
0x00000000004010bd <+70>:    mov    0x4025c0(,%rax,4),%eax
0x00000000004010c4 <+77>:    add    %eax,%ecx
0x00000000004010c6 <+79>:    cmp    $0xf,%eax
0x00000000004010c9 <+82>:    jne    0x4010b8 <phase_5+65>
0x00000000004010cb <+84>:    mov    %eax,0xc(%rsp)
0x00000000004010cf <+88>:    cmp    $0xf,%edx
0x00000000004010d2 <+91>:    jne    0x4010da <phase_5+99>
0x00000000004010d4 <+93>:    cmp    0x8(%rsp),%ecx
0x00000000004010d8 <+97>:    je     0x4010df <phase_5+104>
0x00000000004010da <+99>:    callq  0x401574 <explode_bomb>
0x00000000004010df <+104>:   add    $0x18,%rsp
0x00000000004010e3 <+108>:   retq
End of assembler dump.
```

Could someone please tell me if my assumptions so far are correct and what my next steps should be. I've been stuck on this one for hours and I'm getting nowhere.

By examining $0x4028c5 I have determined that the input must be 2 integers (%d %d).
Lines 65-82 is a loop which runs 15 times. $edx acts as a counter and has nothing to do with my input.
I believe that the array 0x4025c0 plays a crucial role in all of this but I have no idea what that role is.

```
gdb$ x/16wd 0x4025c0
0x4025c0 <array.3160>:  10      2       14      7
0x4025d0 <array.3160+16>:       8       12      15      11
0x4025e0 <array.3160+32>:       0       4       1       13
0x4025f0 <array.3160+48>:       3       9       6       5
```

Comment: Have you considered looking at the code with Radare2?  You might find that it's easier to see what's what.

Comment: No I have not. Infact I haven't heard of Radare2 until now. I'm a total beginner when it comes to assembly.

Comment: I tried downloading a Radare2 and I can't  figure out how it works. It's probably gonna be more of a hassle than reading the assembly code for the last 2 phases of the project. If anyone can give me any hint at all it would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I think the loop is not fixed to running 15 times, the `<+82> jne` will be taken whenever `eax` fetched from the table is not value `15`, then when the `15` is finally reached, the amount of loops in `edx` si compared to value `15`, if your value did bounce inside the loop other-many-times than 15, the bomb will explode. How exactly it bounces around = try yourself, I'm in pain whenever I see AT&T syntax, so this hint must be enough. (and there's ongoing summing into `ecx` of values from table, so you want to bounce exactly 15 times, and you have to input expected final sum also).

Comment: And what is the role of the table... indeed it is crucial, but it sort of eludes to me, what's puzzling you. Don't guess what instructions do, use instruction reference guide. The `cltq` (`cdqe` in Intel syntax) will sign extend the `eax` into `rax` making it full 64b value, in your case I see only positive 4b (0-15) values involved, and `eax` is loaded by 32b `mov`s, so it's already zero-extended to 64b `rax` implicitly by CPU, i.e. `cltq` does nothing in this code. Then `mov 0x4025c0(,%rax,4),%eax` loads value from table (Intel syntax `mov eax,[0x4025c0+rax*4]`), and that's basically all.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your hint about %eax and %edx both needing to be 15 was excactly what I needed. The correct input turned out to be 5 and 115.
I got 5 by testing out the table a few times and 115 is the value of %ecx in line 93.
You're the man Ped7g!!